# Laravel Decrypt: ErrorException unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 2 bytes

Tags: laravel

I wrote a [package](https://github.com/pmochine/Laravel-Tongue) for subdomain localization. But out of nowhere decrypting cookies is not working anymore.

My locale test website was working, but I needed to unsecure it to use Laravel valet share. Now when I changed it to valet secure again, my website does not work anymore. I get the ErrorException:

```
unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 2 bytes
```

in

```
//Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php
Row 149.  return $unserialize ? unserialize($decrypted) : $decrypted;
```

I don't know why. I did not change my app_key, I deleted all cookies for my page but still, it does not work (and it worked perfectly for the last 3 weeks).

If you have a look [here](https://github.com/pmochine/Laravel-Tongue/blob/master/src/Localization/Localization.php) or the shortened code:

```
 return decrypt(request()->cookie('tongue-locale'));
```

You see that I'm decrypting my content of the cookie. If you are curious why I need to decrypt my cookie, that is because the middleware "\App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class," is kicking later in.

Does anyone know why it is not working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what happened, but I needed to change my code into this:

```
app('encrypter')->decrypt(request()->cookie(self::COOKIE), false);
```

With "false" the unserialize is ignored. But still, I would love to know why it is not working.

If you translate this part

```
return $unserialize ? unserialize($decrypted) : $decrypted;
```

with variables $unserialize = true and $decrypted = "de" it's clear that it fails, but I wonder why it did not before..

Comment: Guy you saved my life! It's very weird since it worked perfect for me until I've done composer update, maybe is something related to the version... Thank you!

Comment: @Juli15 If I remember correctly Laravel did change it because of a security reason. So that was the reason it did not work after the composer update. They added this unserialize part. Happy that it worked for you too :)

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the issue using this solutions: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/upgrade#upgrade-5.6.30

Add this line:
`protected static $serialize = true;`

To `app\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies.php`

Answer (score 1):

For me it works running next artisan command

```sh
php artisan key:generate
```

Answer (score 1):

Warning! If you have encrypted data.. Wouldnt "php artisan key:generate" make it "undecryptable"..

Answer (score 1):

In my case.. I was already using 'encrypt()' and 'decrypt()' functions and \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class, was doing it again and messing things up!

I removed it from the 'web' array in the $middlewareGroups variable in Kernel.php

/headbangs